# Error de sintaxis en MariaDB 10 al crear una base de datos con fechas

Tags: mariadb

Es la primera vez que utilizo MariaDB 10 y estoy intentando crear una base de datos de prueba. En unos campos calculados (Virtuales) quiero mostrar el día y el mes de un campo fecha y da error en las funciones DAY() o DAYOFMONTH y MONTH. Si quito los campos Dia y Mes ya no da error. No sé cuál es el error de sintaxis.

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba(
Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
FecNac date NULL,
Dia int AS DAY(FecNac),
Mes int AS MONTH(FecNac),
 CONSTRAINT PK_Miembros PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    Id ASC
)
```

)

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAY(FecNac),
Mes int AS MONTH(FecNac),
CONSTRAINT PK_Miembros PRIMARY...' at line 4**

Comment: El error de sintaxis es porque estás intentando usar `as DAY(XX)` en un campo al crear la tabla... cuando `as` se usa en un select para nombrar la columna (darle un alias). Para indicar un valor por defecto se usa `default XX` según la [documentación](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/default/). Recomiendo encarecidamente siempre repasar la documentación :)

Answer (score 0):

Da la sensación de que intentas hacer algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE Prueba(
  Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  FecNac date,
  Dia int,
  Mes int
);
UPDATE Prueba 
  SET Dia=DAY(FecNac),Mes=MONTH(FecNac);
```

Si realmente necesitas tanto los campos `Dia` y `Mes`, puedes meter ese `UPDATE` en un disparador para que se ejecute en cualquier cambio en la tabla `Prueba`. Pero te adelanto que un campo calculado no debería almacenarse en la base de datos porque es una redundancia que, de no actualizarse en cada cambio, acabará en una inconsistencia.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.